# how to pass a int[] directly in a function?

Tags: java

is it possible to pass a int array `int[]` directly to a function like:

```
foo(int[] param){...}
```

?

If yes, how? I tired s.th. like `foo({1,2})` but it does not work

Comment: Did you really search before asking ?

Comment: @ZouZou I can't think of a good phrase to search. And I didn't expect the question receive so much down-votes. In fact, I always did `int a={1,2};foo(a)` a year before.

Comment: @johnchen902 Google -> java pass array to function -> third result (http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_we_pass_array_to_function_of_java)

Comment: @ZouZou The 6th on my screen, and I usually give up before 5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When used outside a standalone array declaration, the compiler expects the anonymous `int` array syntax:

```
foo(new int[] {1,2});
```

[Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) are a great alternative and less cumbersome option in terms of notation.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider a varargs method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

```
public void foo(int...) { }
```

Then you could call your method as follows:

```
foo(1, 2, 3);
```